# Bad queries error handling in Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Spark Streaming application that has multiple data flows (DStreams) that write in the same Cassandra table. When testing my application on a large amount of random data, I'm receiving an error from Spark Cassandra Connector that has very little information helpful for debugging. The error looks like this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty
    at com.baynote.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.baynote.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.baynote.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD$$anonfun$fetchIterator$1.apply(CassandraJoinRDD.scala:268)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD$$anonfun$fetchIterator$1.apply(CassandraJoinRDD.scala:268)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Key may not be empty
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:184)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:798)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:617)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:831)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:254)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

The problem with it is that I can't tell which DStream, and which data cause it. I can check every DStream that writes to Cassandra, or write my own data validator, but I'm looking for a more generic solution.

The other problem is that it the error kills the whole job instead of ignoring it and continue writing other data. Basically in case of simple non-spark writing I would catch the exception, log it and continue writing the rest of the data. Is there a way to do something like that in Spark Cassandra Connector?

So is there something I can do about those two problems?

Comment: How you are saving the data? Is it rdd or data frame, using case class or normal way?

Comment: It is an RDD of tuples.

Comment: instead of tuples, try case class with default values and you can also write some validation to check your input data.

Comment: The thing that I don't know where exactly it happens, so validating all data would require quite some effort and I wanted to confirm that it's indeed the recommended way and there's no better more generic way of doing it. Also what exactly problem case classes would solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think we should consider two cases:

1. Validate your input data to make sure data for Key (in cassandra columns) is not Null or invalid data format
2. Your data is RDD, so you can sort to ignore invalid data before calling save method.